# $in doesn't work inside $or in MONGO CAKEPHP

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp, database

Hi I have a query where $in is to be used inside $or because there are two set of conditions.

```
(

    [conditions] => Array
        (
            [$or] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => Array
                                (
                                    [$in] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 53fc47ee6eb2361111ba4364
                                            [1] => 53fc48336eb2361311ba4360
                                            [2] => 53fc48716eb2361411ba4360
                                        )

                                 )

                         )

                )

       )

)
```

It is giving me an empty result but if skip $or and directly use id under conditions it will give me desired result. Following format is working fine. But as you know i need $or for second set of conditions.

```
(

    [conditions] => Array
        (
            [id] => Array
               (
                   [$in] => Array
                       (
                           [0] => 53fc47ee6eb2361111ba4364
                           [1] => 53fc48336eb2361311ba4360
                           [2] => 53fc48716eb2361411ba4360
                       )

                )

       )

)
```

Again, I need $or because I need to have two set of conditions inside or. I only displayed one here.

I am using ICHIKAWAY CAKEPHP MONGO Plugin.

Please help !!!

Comment: What's the actual query that isn't working? Have you tried running the equivalent query in the `mongo` shell to confirm results will be returned?

Comment: Yes I tried that in Mongo shell and it was working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Use `$in` in  ICHIKAWAY CAKEPHP MONGO Plugin:

```
$this->paginate = array('conditions' => array(
            'category' => array('$in'=>array('123', 'a', 'abc')))
        );
```

Above code will select all categories in `array('123', 'a', 'abc')`

I hope this will help